# How to return an object from a class in Python without using global variables

Tags: python, regex, function, class, object

I am trying to return the region from my `__maketracker__` method in my `Tracker` class.
Every time I run this code, region is identified as the global variable and not the one returned from my class. If I delete `region=""` (the global variable) then it gives me an error that says region is undefined.
`line` is from an input file.

```
temp = ""
begining = ""
end = ""
flag = ""
region = ""

class Tracker(object):   

    def __init__(self,region):
        self.region = region

    def __maketracker__(self):
        self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show card detail\'',line)
        if self.region:
            self.region = "CPM OR IOM"
            region = self.region
            return region

with open ('/home/SAMPLE.TXT','r') as f:

    for line in f:    
        #This is where I am calling the class
        first = Tracker(line)
        first.__maketracker__()

        if region =="CPM or IOM":
            print "CPM or IOM"
```

Comment: Double underscore is reserved for python internal methods, don't use it for methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first` is the object you created, so one way to access the variable is directly as follows:

```
if first.region == "CPM or IOM":
    print("CPM or IOM")
```

The problem with your program is that you don't do anything with the returned valued.  It should be as follows:

```
region_ = first.__maketracker__()
if region_ == "CPM or IOM":
    print ...
```

So, if we remove all globals and rewrite:

```
class Tracker(object):   

    def __init__(self, region):
        self.region = region

    def make_tracker(self):
        self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show card detail\'', line)
        if self.region:
            self.region = "CPM OR IOM"
            return self.region

with open ('/home/SAMPLE.TXT','r') as f:
    for line in f:    
        first = Tracker(line)
        region = first.make_tracker()
        if region =="CPM or IOM":
            print "CPM or IOM"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `region` in `maketracker`, so you have to assign it to a variable in the callee:

```
with open ('/home/SAMPLE.TXT','r') as f:
    for line in f:    
        #This is where I am calling the class
        first = Tracker(line)
        region = first.__maketracker__()

        if region == "CPM or IOM":
            print "CPM or IOM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Just eliminate the use of the globals. Use the object to store attributes.

Not tested, but something like:

```
class Tracker(object):   

    def __init__(self,region):
        self.region = region

    def maketracker(self, line):
        if re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show card detail\'',line):
            self.region = "CPM OR IOM"
            return self.region
```